# Can I use a braided flexible supply on a Polybutylene Qest Shutoff Valve?

Tags: plumbing

I was repairing my leaky old qest PB angle valves in preparation to replace my faucets, and I overtightened a nut and broke it.  Can I replace the 3/8" supply line with a flexible braided supply with the integrated nut?  The nut on the qest fitting is 1/2" but the supply inlet is 3/8", so I'm not positive that this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I purchased a 1/2" IPS braided supply but the design doesn't permit the inner sealing cone to sit within the 3/8" opening in the quest valve, making it impossible to use.  It seems the only option with these is the original type nut and a 3/8" OD supply tube/line.